# Different results in matrix multiplication using Python and R language

Tags: python, r, numpy, matrix

I am transcripting a multi-layer perceptron algorithm from R program to python, however I am facing with a problem, the matrix multiplication has given me a different results:

R language:

```
> hidden <- matrix(c(-0.4442772, -0.1844143, 0.2783537, 0.2599441, -0.3190043, 0.2062185), nrow=2, ncol=3) 
> Xp <- c(0, 1, 1)
> hidden %*% Xp

           [,1]
[1,] -0.0406506
[2,]  0.4661626
```

Python:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> Xp = np.array([0, 1, 1])
>>> hidden = np.asmatrix([[-0.4442772, -0.1844143, 0.2783537], [0.2599441, -0.3190043, 0.2062185]])
>>> np.dot(hidden, nq)

matrix([[ 0.0939394, -0.1127858]])
```

Using the [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B-0.4442772,%20-0.1844143,%20%200.2783537%7D,%20%7B0.2599441,%20-0.3190043,%20%200.2062185%7D%7D*%7B0,1,%201%7D), Python would be right, but even that it is not converging to the right result of algorithm. I searched for its difference between both languages in this aspects and did not find nothing. Besides that, I applied another matrix multiplication to test and both results was equal:

R language:

```
> m1 <- matrix(c(2,3,4,7,0,1), nrow = 3, ncol=2)
> m2 <- matrix(c(1,6,4,3,6,9), nrow = 2, ncol=3)
> m1 %*% m2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   44   29   75
[2,]    3   12   18
[3,]   10   19   33
```

Python:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> m1 = np.matrix([[2,7], [3,0], [4,1]])
>>> m2 = np.matrix([[1,4,6], [6,3,9]])
>>> np.dot(m1,m2)

matrix([[44, 29, 75],
        [ 3, 12, 18],
        [10, 19, 33]])
```

What is the difference in this case? And how can I reach this results in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you print the matrix you create:

```
#           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] -0.4442772 0.2783537 -0.3190043
#[2,] -0.1844143 0.2599441  0.2062185
```

That's not the same as your Wolfram Alpha link shows.

You get the same result as in python and Mathematica if you create the same matrix:

```
hidden <- matrix(c(-0.4442772, -0.1844143, 0.2783537, 0.2599441, -0.3190043, 0.2062185), nrow=2, ncol=3, 
            byrow = TRUE) #fill matrix by row instead of default by column 
#           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] -0.4442772 -0.1844143 0.2783537
#[2,]  0.2599441 -0.3190043 0.2062185
Xp <- c(0, 1, 1)
hidden %*% Xp
#           [,1]
#[1,]  0.0939394
#[2,] -0.1127858
```

Comment: Very nice, I did not have the knowledge about byrow fill. And I was using cat instead of print. Is my first contact with R language.
Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I haven't used `cat` in a very long time. Use cases for it are rare in R.